# clear nib cache on iphone device

Tags: iphone, caching, internationalization, nib, xib

Like many i have internationalized my app.  On the simulator I am able to easily delete the cache so that the new NIB files will display but testing on the device, only the old NIB will show which is in the devices cache.

cleaning all targets is not the solution, and neither is deleting the app on the device since it holds data that I don't want my users who update to loose.

Will the update process on iTunes clear the cache when the app is distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update completely overwrites application bundle, so you shouldn't worry about that.